# How to draw borders and separators on a View

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an App, and I need to draw borders and separators on a View, like the eBay app.

I think on a combination of shapes and view with 1dp. There is another easy way?

[image: ebay App.]
Many thanks.

Comment: Are you going to use a ListView or Views in LinearLayout?

Comment: +Gallal, im trying to use Views inside a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 9-patch image for the outside border.  Use that as the background resource and it will give you the rounded corners with solid border.  For dividers, you can create a simple view and have another background resource that's a simple image with the same color as the border in the 9-patch.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedborder"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Put Saved Searches display code here.  Probably LinearLayout/horizonal -->
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/simpleborder"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"/> <!-- Spacer! -->

        <!-- Put Favorite sellers display code here.  Probably LinearLayout/horizonal -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, It's seems this is the easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

or you could use margins at the bottom, for the view which is just above the empty space.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
```

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain?, i was explaining an alternative for a view with 1dp height.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how the views are grouped together so that some have curved corners on top, others in the bottom plus padding or a margin, and others with no curved corners at all, then this is one way to do it.

If you are using ListView with ListAdapter then When overriding `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` determine from `position` what view should be returned and return it.  You can change the view's padding and margins before returning it.

Also, it'll be more efficient if you override `getItemViewType(int position)` and return a constant representation a view type for a specific position so that Android can reuse views and you wont have to inflate a new one or change the attributes every time.

Comment: Im trying to use Views inside a LinearLayout. But I'll keep this answer for future developments, thanks!